# Delete files older than 24 hours and empty directories using find

Tags: find, cron

I have these cron tasks to manage the automatic deletion of backups after 24 hours.

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/foo/backups && mkdir -p $(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)
0,30 * * * * find /home/foo/backups -name "foo.*.sql.gz" -mmin +1440 -exec rm {} \;
0,30 * * * * find /home/foo/backups -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
0,30 * * * * mysqldump -ufoo -pbar foo | gzip > /home/foo/backups/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)/foo.$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d.\%H\%M).sql.gz
```

What I am seeing is that after 24 hours, I end up with a /home/foo/backups folder with nothing in it, whereas I am expecting to see a folder e.g. /home/backups/2013-11-20 for the previous day with backups in it.

What's wrong with the syntax above?

Comment: You are wasting others time by not providing complete information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no backup created on any of the three lines. Maybe you are missing a line.

Let's analyze every command on detail:

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/foo/backups && mkdir -p $(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)
```

At 0.0 every day, it goes to `/home/foo/backups` and creates a dir on the format `2013-11-20`. (You could also say `mkdir -p /home/foo/backups/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)`).

```
0,30 * * * * find /home/foo/backups -name "foo.*.sql.gz" -mmin +1440 -exec rm {} \;
```

At 0.30 every day it looks for files `foo.*.sql.gz` in `/home/foo/backups` that are older than 24 hours. They are deleted.

```
0,30 * * * * find /home/foo/backups -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

At 0.30 every day it looks for empty subdirectories of `/home/foo/backups`. They are deleted.

Comment: Sorry, there is another cron task which creates the backup and the backups are successfully created.

Comment: Update your question with full info, otherwise there is no sense to ask for help. What's the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove files find /your-path -mtime -1 –print | xargs rm -f

Answer (score 0):

Edited question to add all cron tasks and realised the problem is in the order of tasks.

The backup needs to get created *before* the delete task runs otherwise the folder will be empty and will get deleted and the backup will not be able to get created. D'oh!